# Update to a specific revision of a branch

Tags: svn

I want to get the code as it was in a specific revision of an earlier branch. My working copy is switched to another branch right now. Note I want to only do this for specific directory.

My svn version is 
svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011)

Comment: Are you using svn 1.7? or what version are you using? There were big changes in the local copy handling in 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you're in ORIGINATING_BRANCH and the version of the file you're interested in is in TARGET_BRANCH

I'd do it like this:

```
svn switch https://%REPO%/branches/%TARGET_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE% -r %VERSION% %FILE%
```

If you want to commit it back into your initial branch, you'll need to switch back:

```
svn switch https://%REPO%/branches/%ORIGINATING_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE% %FILE%
svn commit %FILE% -m "%MESSAGE%"
```

**Be careful:** on the second switch you'll need to merge both versions (the old one with your newer modifications, and the other), so you better save a backup copy of your changes before switching back.

If you want to use *svn merge* simply do something like:

```
svn merge https://%REPO%/branches/%TARGET_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE%@version https://%REPO%/branches/%ORIGINATING_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE%
```

Comment: What if I want to commit to the currently switched branch?

Comment: With the currently switched branch you mean ORIGINATING_BRANCH or TARGET_BRANCH? If it's in ORIGINATING_BRANCH then I've answered it in the edit.

Comment: Yes I meant originating branch. Can we somehow use svn merge to achieve same thing, i.e get my working copy to be same as earlier release branch?

Comment: Yes, you can do something akin to: svn merge https://%REPO%/branches/%TARGET_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE%@version https://%REPO%/branches/%ORIGINATING_BRANCH%/%DIR%/%FILE%